# How to make full screen (no matter screen size) software with neatbeans gui menu?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, fullscreen

I'm trying to make an application for educational purpose with the Netbeans GUI builder. I want to make a fullscreen app which adapts to any screen size.

I know how to make the screen maximized, but the problem is the organisation of the window I made with the GUI builder. How can I tell the GUI builder that I want a component (let's take the example of 'label' 'cause that's what it's all about in my program) with 80% width of the screen? I tried with `jLabel.setsize` but it doesn't do anything, I think it's because the builder assigns some constants.

I don't really understand how the GUI works, because when in the builder I made the `jlabel` with a 100% width, it covers well the 100% of the screen when I launch the program. However, when I put 80% in the GUI for example, it covers 50% once launched (approximately)

**How I make the program full screen:**

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
      setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
});
```

**How I try to change the jlabel dimension :**

```
jLabel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 100));
```

I expect to have a GUI builder which could adapt to the screen size, but it doesn't presently.

Comment: It all boils down to the [Layout Manager(s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) you use for your JFrame and other Panels or Panes. You will need to lean how to utilize these Layout Managers and just so you know...it's well worth the time to do this **now**.

Comment: Hey, hum actually the layout manager part is auto generated, so I can't modify it. I just want the frame made by the gui builder automatly adapt when I put the window in fullscreen